# JavaScript show/hide tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, show-hide

What i want is hide all content first, then click one tab, the corresponding content shows (the tab becomes 'active'), where click it again it will disappear. some of the tabs are just a 'mailto' link.

problem is i can't hide the tabs when click again

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav div').hide();
    $('#nav div:first').show();
    $('#nav ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#nav ul li a').click(function(){ 
        $('#nav div').hide();
        $('#nav ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
        if($(currentTab).css('display')=='none'){
            $(currentTab).show();
        }else{
            $(currentTab).hide();
        }

    }
);
});
```

the navigation code is the following:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:email">Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="about">
      about
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      contact
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having? which part is not working?

Comment: oh im sorry! not being to hide the tabs when click again. i've updated the question.

Comment: What do you want to happen when an emailto link is clicked?

Comment: @richard just initiate the email client, no content shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav div').hide();
    $('#nav div:first').show();
    $('#nav ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#nav ul li a').click(function(){
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        var vis = $(currentTab).is(':visible');
        $('#nav div').hide();
        $('#nav ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if(vis) {
            $(currentTab).hide();
        } else {
            $(currentTab).show();
        }
    });
});
```

you have to check if the current tab is visible **before** you hide it.

working: http://jsfiddle.net/tqhHA/

Answer (score 1):

Change the click function to:

```
$('#nav ul li a').click(function(){ 
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');  
    $('#nav div').not(currentTab).hide();
    $('#nav ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');     
    if (currentTab.indexOf("mailto:") === -1)
    {
        $(currentTab).toggle();
    }
});
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/ovolik/2/edit)

Comment: sorry i tried this but not quite work as the second click won't hide the tabs. but it's highly possible that i implemented it wrong, thanks!!!

Comment: i found in the example that when the content of 'about' is shown, clicking 'about' again wont hide the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav div').hide();
$('#nav div:first').show();
$('a').click(function(){    
    var currentTab = '#'+$(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if($(currentTab).is(':visible')){
        $('#nav div').hide();
        $(currentTab).hide();
    }else{
        $('#nav div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
    }
}
);
});


<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="about">
      about
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      contact
    </div>
</div>
```

Please try above code..
I change href value to just "#" then some change in jquery. Please ask in comment if you have any doubt.. [click here to test](http://jsfiddle.net/HVk4A/1/)