# Javascript change margin-top and slowly show other div on click

Tags: javascript, html

Im busy with an mobile website design, but im not that good with javascript. So i would like to have an startup script which i can modify. So i dont know where to start.

What i want to achieve is the following:

When you click on an button/div (onclick function) an div **slides** up (change margin top/make an invisble div that slides in height). And on the same click an other div **slides** open. (So the second div isnt shown at first but on click it is shown.

I dont know if this is possible but im sure you guys know if it is.

Kind regards,

Augus

Answer (score 0):

yeah it can be done easily with Jquery. you can even set sliding speed. 
you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324887/javascript-show-hide-tab) thread and you can do something similar. I have answered in that thread as well.

or you can do it using below function:

```
jQuery('#div_id_1').slideDown("slow");
jQuery('#div_id_2').slideUp("slow");
```